# Issue while importing gradle project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, import

I am facing import issue while importing the gradle project in eclipse. In my build.gradle file there is below entry for environment variable.

```
buildscript {
    // Usually, the ext in gradle build script is used to define constants.
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "1.3.3.RELEASE"
        ENV = System.getenv()
        platformJar = ENV["skyfall_sdk"]
        generatedDocumentation = file('src/docs/asciidoc/generated')
    }
```

How to set environment variables in eclipse to provide value for "skyfall_sdk", so import is successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting an environment variable in Eclipse, follow this :

In the menu "Run" -> "Run Configuration" -> Then click on your compilator and in the new window, you can select "Environment".

[image]

Then you select "New..." and make a variable for "skyfall_sdk".